# php artisan migrate:install won't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I just started downloading laravel 5 today. Where I install my laravel in my desktop. When I try to create a database using laravel comman php artisan migrate:install and it give's me a error `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'forge'` I tried a lot of examples on google but didn't work for me. 
[image: SC]

I follow on of the steps on the internet where I configure my `.env` file followed the array contain in `database.php` database to `'forge'`, username to `'forge'` and password to `''`

**database.php**

```
   'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],

    'pgsql' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' => 'public',
    ],

],
```

**.env**

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:oqZ6S+IZANLCbszbhef9VSPqd/4rw22oT0mixzsflZo=
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=forge
DB_USERNAME=forge
DB_PASSWORD=''

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

How can I create database just typing `php artisan migrate:install` and  automatically create `laravel_migration` database in my localhost? Just saw this on the internet. But when I did this it didn't create for me.

Comment: Do you have `mysql` user and a database named `forge`on your localhost?

Comment: Change `DB_USERNAME` to your mysql username(default:root) and `DB_PASSWORD` to mysql password(default:empty) and log into mysql and create a database with whatever name you want and add it to `DB_DATABASE`

Comment: I think you need to provide database access privileges to user **forge** for database **forge**. Have you chosen same name `forge` for username and database name? First, please verify your mysql db credentials.

Comment: @RavishaHesh Actually my DB_PASSWORD and DB_USERNAME is default. What should I do here next?

Comment: @RifkiAriaGumelar No I didn't have. But my `DB_PASSWORD` and `DB_USERNAME` is default.

Comment: Do you have vagrant/homestead installed? You're trying to run the artisan command from your windows machine, where the environment variables from your `.env` are not available. Run the artisan command from inside vagrant. `vagrant ssh; cd <your project directory>; php artisan migrate:install`

Comment: @jsphpl I didn't know what do you mean. I just followed the steps on what I saw. what should put inside this `<your project directory>`?

Comment: Default `mysql` username is `root`. Anyway, try to create a new `mysql` user with a password then set it as `DB_USERNAME` and `DB_PASSWORD` values. Then create a new database for example `laravel` and set `DB_DATABASE=laravel`.

Comment: @RifkiAriaGumelar  still encounter the same error. How can I create database just typing `php artisan migrate:install` and automatically create `laravel_migration`?

Comment: Laravel will not create a database, you should create it using [workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) or follow step 1 on this [tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Database-in-MySQL)

Comment: I suggest you install homestead: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead This way all the examples will work out of the box. Remember to always log in to homestead (via the `vagrant ssh` command) when executing `php artisan` commands. All is left to do then is to create a database in homestead.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the tutorial assumes you are using their development virtual machine. Since you're not, you need to start up MySQL and do the following:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS forge;
CREATE USER forge@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON forge.* TO forge@localhost;
```

Once the database and user are created, you should be good to go. This should be part of their documentation...